# Call rpc from Erlang node to Elixir node

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to call rpc from Erlang to Elixir, I get:

```
rpc:call(chat@localhost, 'Node' , 'list', []).

{badrpc,{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Node',list,[],[]},
                        {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                             [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,197}]}]}}}
```

Whats the proper syntax for achieving this simple call?

Answer (score 7):

When Elixir code gets compiled, the module names actually become `Elixir.Module`. So in order to call an Elixir module from Erlang, you will need to use `'Elixir.Module'`. In this case,

```
rpc:call('chat@localhost', 'Elixir.Node', list, [])
```